# NL and other languages visible, but English site not visible and showing error after translating news item

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, navigation

I get below error when try to reach [my site](http://www.bo-medical.com/) (see screenshot):

The *editor* of the site made a news item and translated it to English. Now [the English](http://www.bo-medical.com/) (default) site can't be reached. But the other languages are still working. For example [the dutch version](http://www.bo-medical.com/nl).

> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in tb_megamenu_insert_tb_item() (line 347
>   of
>   /var/www/clients/client7/web17/web/sites/all/modules/tb_megamenu/tb_megamenu.functions.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: href in include() (line 2 of
>   /var/www/clients/client7/web17/web/sites/all/modules/tb_megamenu/templates/tb-megamenu-item.tpl.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: href in include() (line 2 of
>   /var/www/clients/client7/web17/web/sites/all/modules/tb_megamenu/templates/tb-megamenu-item.tpl.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: options in include() (line 2 of
>   /var/www/clients/client7/web17/web/sites/all/modules/tb_megamenu/templates/tb-megamenu-item.tpl.php).
>   Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to url() must be of the
>   type array, null given, called in
>   /var/www/clients/client7/web17/web/sites/all/modules/tb_megamenu/templates/tb-megamenu-item.tpl.php
>   on line 2 and defined in url() (line 2220 of
>   /var/www/clients/client7/web17/web/includes/common.inc).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error msgs shown, it seems that you're using the [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) module. So think of a way to get that module disabled (eg using the Dutch admin screens to disable a module, or using Drush if you have it available). That might possibly help to get rid of those errors again.

If you then also unpublish (or delete?) that news item where your problems started from, you may have a stable situation again. And from there continue your investigation to find the real cause (root) of your issue.

Doei!